# The Static Classes in Java

Tags: java

I was looking at some of the shape classes in the java.awt.geom package when I noticed that most of the classes such as Ellipse2D.Double, Arc2D.Double, etc are defined as static.

I've seen what static fields and methods of a class are, but what does it mean for a class to be static? Does it just mean that all of it's fields and methods are static or is there more to it?

Comment: I'm just asking about a simple static class, not nested. I did notice that thread but I don't want to go that deep.

Comment: There are no static classes that are not nested.

Comment: Ellipse2D.Double is nested inside Ellipse2D.